# How to sort table rows given that the row weight is already known?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Table:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

The table data is present in an array (see `table_matrics`). The array is sorted and the `weight_index` keeps track of the changes in the order (in this case `[1, 1, 1]`).

```
var desc            = true;

var weight_index    = [];

var table_matrics   = [1, 2, 3];

table_matrics.sort(function(a, b){
    var weight;

    if(a == b)
    {
        weight  = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        weight  = (desc ? a > b : a < b) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    weight_index.push(weight);

    return weight;
});
```

How to sort/re-render the table rows using the `weight_index`?

Comment: I don't understand very well what `weight_index` does.

Comment: If you have an array `[1,2,3]` that you want to sort in a descending order, then you need to move first element -1 and second element -1, to get `[3,2,1]`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: But I don't understand. If it returns `-1`, the first element has a lower index than the second one. Then, with `[-1,-1]`, the array `[1,2,3]` stays the same instead of being reversed.

Comment: Yes, there is no advantage to generate the `weight_index` additional array.

Comment: @Stano, you need `weight_index` to reorder elements in the table. See my example code below.

Comment: @Oriol, see the MDN link if you don't understand how the weights work.

Comment: @Guy But after running your code, `table_matrics` remains `[1,2,3]` instead of being the reverse. The link says *if `compareFunction(a, b)` is less than 0, sort `a` to a lower index than `b`*. Then, if `weight_index` is `[-1,-1]`, `table_matrics` doesn't change.

Comment: @Oriol, sorry, you are actually right. `weight_index` should have been `[1, 1, 1]`. That doesn't change the question, though.

Comment: Curiously, on IE it's `[1,-1,1]` because it compares the elements in other order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach. I am cloning the the `tbody` of the table. Then sort the rows in the jQuery object and replace the present `tbody` body with the sorted rows.

```
var data    = tbody.clone();

var i       = 0;

data        = data.find('tr').sort(function()
{
    return weight_index[i++];
});

tbody.html(data);
```

Though, it is relatively slow. With 10,000+ records it takes ~300ms. Furthermore, a jQuery-less approach is preferable.

Posting this in case someone else might find it simple enough for their needs.

---

After hours of restless thinking, I've ended up with the following. If this sample isn't enough, I've written a whole blog post explaining the logic behind it, http://anuary.com/57/sorting-large-tables-with-javascript.

```
// Will use this to re-attach the tbody object.
var table       = tbody.parent();

// Detach the tbody to prevent unnecessary overhead related
// to the browser environment.
var tbody       = tbody.detach();

// Convert NodeList into an array.
rows            = Array.prototype.slice.call(rows, 0);

var last_row    = rows[data[data.length-1].index];

// Knowing the last element in the table, move all the elements behind it
// in the order they appear in the data map
for(var i = 0, j = data.length-1; i < j; i++)
{
    tbody[0].insertBefore(rows[data[i].index], last_row);

    // Restore the index.
    data[i].index   = i;
}

// Restore the index.
data[data.length-1].index   = data.length-1;

table.append(tbody);
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/rJe2U/1/

```
var desc            = true,
    weight_index    = [],
    table_matrics   = [1, 2, 3],
    tb=document.getElementById('tb'),
    rowsCollection=tb.rows,
    rows=[];

try{
    rows=Array.prototype.slice.call(rowsCollection,0);
}catch(e){
    for(var i=0,l=rowsCollection.length;i<l;i++){
        rows.push(rowsCollection[i]);
    }
}

table_matrics.sort(function(a, b){
    var weight;
    if(a == b){
        weight  = 0;
    }else{
        weight  = (desc ? a > b : a < b) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    weight_index.push(weight);
    if(weight>0){
        tb.insertBefore(rows[b-1], rows[a-1])
    }else if(weight<0){
        tb.insertBefore(rows[a-1], rows[b-1])
    }
    return weight;
});
```

According to http://jsperf.com/sorting-table-rows-with-known-row-weight, the performance is about 41,000 ops/second (12,300 ops/300ms), so it's a bit faster than your code.

**Edit:**

The code above can be simplified (http://jsfiddle.net/rJe2U/2/):

```
var desc            = true,
    weight_index    = [],
    table_matrics   = [1, 2, 3],
    tb=document.getElementById('tb'),
    rows=[];

try{
    rows=Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows,0);
}catch(e){
    for(var i=0,rowsCollection=tb.rows,l=rowsCollection.length;i<l;i++){
        rows.push(rowsCollection[i]);
    }
}

table_matrics.sort(function(a, b){
    var weight;
    if(a == b){
        weight  = 0;
    }else{
        if(desc ? a > b : a < b){
            weight=-1;
            tb.insertBefore(rows[a-1], rows[b-1]);
        }else{
            weight=1;
            tb.insertBefore(rows[b-1], rows[a-1]);
        }
    }
    weight_index.push(weight);
    return weight;
});
```

And you dont need `weight_index`, so it can be removed ( http://jsfiddle.net/rJe2U/3/ ):

```
var desc            = true,
    table_matrics   = [1, 2, 3],
    tb=document.getElementById('tb'),
    rows=[];

try{
    rows=Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows,0);
}catch(e){
    for(var i=0,rowsCollection=tb.rows,l=rowsCollection.length;i<l;i++){
        rows.push(rowsCollection[i]);
    }
}

table_matrics.sort(function(a, b){
    var weight;
    if(a == b){
        return 0;
    }
    if(desc ? a > b : a < b){
        tb.insertBefore(rows[a-1], rows[b-1]);
        return -1;
    }
    tb.insertBefore(rows[b-1], rows[a-1]);
    return 1;
});
```

The performance doesn't seem to improve ( http://jsperf.com/sorting-table-rows-with-known-row-weight/3 ), but I think that with large amount of rows it will.